# How to resolve the error : No signature of method: build_3ov23u7xor54ble5ncs4vfgan.android() is applicable for argument

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle, flutter-packages, flutter-js

Hello everyone I'm asking for help here because after a week of searching and trying I still can't solve an error, preventing me from recompiling my flutter application into an android version.

Here are the facts: After installing the flutter_js package, impossible to launch the application on android the complete error is the following:
Build file 'D:\Nouveau dossier\projet\android\app\build.gradle' line: 28
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> No signature of method: build_3ov23u7xor54ble5ncs4vfgan.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_3ov23u7xor54ble5ncs4vfgan$_run_closure2) values: [build_3ov23u7xor54ble5ncs4vfgan$_run_closure2@1d78c292]

This is my gradle configuration : -

[image]

I tried to solve it by reading all the similar posts on this and other forums but no result.
Thank you so much for your help!
Simeon

Comment: have you tried `flutter clean` before recompiling the app?

Comment: is use flutter_js: ^0.6.0  ?

Comment: yes i tried flutter clean and i use flutter_js: ^0.6.0

Comment: Your path to the project has a space in it, this is warned against when installing flutter (check the docs). I don't know if it is causing your specific problem though.