# I was trying to run an old flutter code in which it has Tflite has been used

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, tflite

while debugging I tried my code on the web which is working but I'm building an Android app so when I tried on the emulator it is given an error.

[image]

what should I do now?
Here is the repo link: https://github.com/LoftyDroid/Plant-Disease-Detector

Comment: Please double-check your build.gradle for possible typos:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68845460/421195 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75040638/.  Also, please copy/paste the TEXT of your error message! Screen shots are discouraged.